# How do I add poles to this Biquad Filter for more rolloff

Tags: lowpass-filter, java

I now want a filter that has less of the frequencies to be cutoff. I would like a filter with 36, 48 or more decibels of rolloff

Code

````
public class BiquadFilter implements ISimpleFilter {
    
    // instance variables
    private double cutOffFrequency;
    private int sampleRate;
    private double resonance;
    private boolean highPass;
    private double alpha;
    private double cutoffAmount;
    private double resonanceAmount;
    private double shelfSlope;
    private double[] a;
    private double[] b;
    private double valueZero;
    private double valueOne;
    private double filteredValueZero;
    private double filteredValueOne;
    
    // constructor
    public BiquadFilter(double cutoffFrequency, int sampleRate, byte resonace, 
            boolean highPass) {
        this.cutOffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.resonance = resonace / 127;
        this.highPass = highPass;
        cutoffAmount = 2 * Math.PI * cutoffFrequency / sampleRate;
        alpha = Math.sin(cutoffAmount) / (2 * (1 + resonance * 6));
        
        a = new double[3];
        b = new double[3];
        
        if (highPass) {
            
            b[1] = 1 + Math.cos(cutoffAmount);
            b[0] = b[1] / 2;
            b[2] = b[0];
            b[1] *= -1;
        } else {
            
            b[1] = 1 - Math.cos(cutoffAmount);
            b[0] = b[1] / 2;
            b[2] = b[0];
        }
        
        a[0] = 1 + alpha;
        a[1] = -(2 * Math.cos(cutoffAmount));
        a[2] = 1 - alpha;
        
        valueZero = 0;
        valueOne = 0;
        filteredValueZero = 0;
        filteredValueOne = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCutoff(double cutoffFrequency) {
        this.cutOffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        cutoffAmount = 2 * Math.PI * cutoffFrequency / sampleRate;
        alpha = Math.sin(cutoffAmount) / (2 * (1 + resonance * 6));
        
        if (highPass) {
            
            b[1] = 1 + Math.cos(cutoffAmount);
            b[0] = b[1] / 2;
            b[2] = b[0];
            b[1] *= -1;
        } else {
            
            b[1] = 1 - Math.cos(cutoffAmount);
            b[0] = b[1] / 2;
            b[2] = b[0];
        }
        
        a[0] = 1 + alpha;
        a[1] = -(2 * Math.cos(cutoffAmount));
        a[2] = 1 - alpha;
    }

    @Override
    public double filter(double point) {
        
        // method variables
        double returnValue;
        
        returnValue = (b[0] / a[0]) * point + (b[1] / a[0]) * valueZero 
                + (b[2] / a[0]) * valueOne
                - (a[1] / a[0]) * filteredValueZero - (a[2] / a[0]) 
                * filteredValueOne;
        
        valueOne = valueZero;
        valueZero = point;
        
        filteredValueOne = filteredValueZero;
        filteredValueZero = returnValue;
        
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: That's a bit of an unusual implementation. I'm guessing you would be way better off using RBJ's standard audio cookbook: https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html

Comment: I have implemented single pole, two pole and a sinc filter, maybe I need a filter that is in between the two-pole and sinc filters. Is there a way I could turn this filter into a three or four pole filter? https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Impulse_Tracker#IT214_sample_compression

Comment: Have you tried using the correct formula for alpha?

Comment: What is the correct formula?

Comment: @Edward Eddy67716. It’s in the link that Hillary provided.

Comment: @DanSzabo I am using the one for Q which is formula 8, is that the wrong one to use if I want resonance?

Comment: @Edward Eddy67716. It’s equation 7, pretty sure. Why are you doing 1+resonance*6?  Why not just resonance?  If I imagine resonance as meaning Q, then you are applying 6 times as much and have an offset of 1, both of which don’t make sense to me.

Comment: But like that it applies too little resonance with higher frequency cut-offs.

Comment: @Edward Eddy67716.  It may be unlikely that anyone can help you then.  It applies the correct amount of resonance for the given model, which is the well understood biquad analog prototype.  Best of luck.

Comment: Can I add extra poles to this to get less of the frequencies past the cutoff? Something between this filter and a sinc filter.

Comment: Hillary, he says

Comment: I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Which formula is it?